# How can I create an external table using textfile with presto?

Tags: hive, presto

I've a csv file in hdfs directory /user/bzhang/filefortable:

```
123,1
```

And I use the following to create an external table with presto in hive:

```
create table hive.testschema.au1 (count bigint, matched bigint) with (format='TEXTFILE', external_location='hdfs://192.168.0.115:9000/user/bzhang/filefortable');
```

But when I run **select * from au1**, I got

```
presto:testschema> select * from au1;
 count | matched
-------+---------
 NULL  | NULL
```

I changed the comma to the TAB as the delimeter but it still returns NULL. But If I modify the csv as

```
123
```

with only 1 column, the **select * from au1** gives me:

```
presto:testschema> select * from au1;
 count | matched
-------+---------
 123  | NULL
```

So maybe I'm wrong with the file format or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the field delimiter of the table is '\u0001'.

You can change the ',' to '\u0001' or change the field delimiter to ',' , and check your problem was solved

Comment: I misread this answer many times, so to clarify -- Presto expects source files with `format = 'TEXTFILE'` to use the binary character `0x1` as the field separator. As of now, [it's not possible](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/6387) to use the [`ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPT3X_2.1.2/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.bigsql.doc/doc/bsql_create_table_as.html) approach to solve this in Presto. You _must_ feed a `0x1`-separated file for it to be read properly

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression. Although you cannot do it in presto, you can do this modification in hive instead, and presto could recognize that if they share the same hive meta-store